# Do IF when the Var Change

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to do a If in VB.NET when the var change. Example:

```
If var testvar change do this if Then
            Me.RichTextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
        End If
```

Comment: The correct word to use would be "when", not "if". May this guide you one step closer to a solution.

Comment: USE THIS Dim Result = IF(expression,<true return>,<false return>)

Comment: Take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a Class to wrap your variable, and an event that is raised if the variable changes. Your listener (Form) for example, then subscribes to the event and responds to it.

```
Imports System
Class MyClass
  Private x As Integer
  Public Sub SetX(ByVal i As Integer)
    x = i
  End Sub

  Public Function GetX() As Integer
    Return x
  End Function

  Public Event Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  Protected Overridable Sub OnChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Changed(Me, e)
  End Sub
End Class
```

For more info, see here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5041/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-VB-NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877(v=vs.80).aspx